# How to update a large amount of data with Entity Framework Core in C# with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I want to update a large amount of data (around 2 million records) with Entity Framework Core in C# (.NET 6), but I have performance issues.

I tried this:

```
var data = await _context.Set<MyObject>()
                         .Where(x => x.field != string.Empty)
                         .ToListAsync();  

data.ForEach(x => x.field = _myService.GetNewValue(x.field))

_context.Set<MyObject>().UpdateRange(data);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

How can I improve performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Process less rows at a time? What do you define as a performance issue? Just sending that many records over the network is going to take some time.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at executing some SQL directly on the database instead of retrieving data, modifying it and then saving it. The change you're making looks like it could be done that way. I can't recall off the top of my head but I think that the `DbContext` itself has a method for executing SQL code directly. It's not something I do very often and I'm sure it's changed in EF Core but it should not be hard to find out.

Answer (score 2):

- Update to EF Core 7
- Set a high Command Timeout value
- Use the new `ExecuteUpdate` method

or just use a SQL statement or stored procedure, you can call it with the `ExecuteSqlCommand` method in EF Core

Comment: This is the best approach. But when I try `data.ExecuteUpdate(p => p.SetProperty(x => x.field, x => myService.Process(x.field)));`  I got : The following 'SetProperty' failed to translate: 'SetProperty(x => x.field, x => ___myService_0.Process(x.field))'.  In my case te new value is processed by a service and I have to pass the field value like myService.Process(**x.field**), it seems that it can't access the field value when calling the service. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: You cannot do that. If you must do do that, your original approach  is the only viable solution.